# Getting EAV setup to not recreate existing attribute options

Tags: attributes, eav

Currently I have something similar to the following that creates attributes :

```
// $this->_catalogSetup -> Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup
$this->_catalogSetup->addAttribute(
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY,
    'my_attribute_code',
    array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'filterable' => true,
        'label' => 'My Attribute',
        'input' => 'select',
        'option' => array('values' => array(
             'My Option 1',
             'My Option 2'
        )),
        'required' => false,
        'sort_order' => 1,
    )
);
```

However, obviously every time I run this, it create those options again.  I would like this code to be executed multiple times and only ever do an "update". This works fine for the rest of the attribute's details with the exception of the options, is there a way to make it update the options, rather than add to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The facility that you want does not exist in Magento's EAV setup, which should be considered as a convenience device only.

Updating existing options along with other attribute details can be achieved (in this case) by working with the `catalog/resource_eav_attribute` object directly.

See `\Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_AttributeController::saveAction()` and `\Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute::_saveOption()` for implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the tutorial explain how compare with existing attribute options and add new options.
http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/import-attribute-options-magento-2-programmatically/

```
function addNewOptions( $object_Manager, $newOptions, $storeArray ) {

$option = array();
$eavConfig = $object_Manager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color');
$option['attribute_id'] = $attribute->getAttributeId();

foreach($newOptions as $key => $value){

    $option['value'][$value][0]=$value;

    foreach($storeArray as $storeKey => $store) {
        $option['value'][$value][$storeKey] = $value;
    }   
    echo 'Added value : '.$value.PHP_EOL;
}

$eavSetup = $object_Manager->get('\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup');
$eavSetup->addAttributeOption($option);
```

}